# How can I highlight an element on click with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, border, highlight

I am working on a 2-player-game for a group project, where you have to choose an avatar in order to start the game. The chosen avatar is then shown in the actual game.

Therefore I am looking for a solution for the following situations:
1. The chosen image is highlighted with a border, when you click on it.
2. Each player can choose only one avatar (i.e. image) - so the border of an image would be removed if you click on another one.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="col span-1-of-2">
    <h3>Player 1:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" required>
    <div class="avatar">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="avatar">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col span-1-of-2">
    <h3>Player 2:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" required>
    <div class="avatar">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="avatar">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3"><input type="image" id="avatarID" src="super-mario-head.png" onclick="mark('avatarID')"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use radio buttons

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="pl-1-avatar" value="a"> <span>A</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="pl-1-avatar" value="b"> <span>B</span></label>

<label><input type="radio" name="pl-2-avatar" value="a"> <span>A</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="pl-2-avatar" value="b"> <span>B</span></label>
```

than using JavaScript to detect who is who just go for:

```js
const pl1avatar = document.querySelector('[name="pl-1-avatar"]:checked').value;
const pl2avatar = document.querySelector('[name="pl-2-avatar"]:checked').value;
```

and using CSS:

```css
[name$="-avatar"]:checked ~ span {  /* SELECTED STYLE HERE */  }
```

**Demo time:**

```js
const getAvatars = () => {
  const pl1avatar = document.querySelector('[name="pl-1-avatar"]:checked').value;
  const pl2avatar = document.querySelector('[name="pl-2-avatar"]:checked').value;
  console.log(`
    PLAYER 1 AVATAR: ${pl1avatar}
    PLAYER 2 AVATAR: ${pl2avatar}
  `);
}

document.querySelector("#play").addEventListener('click', getAvatars);
```

```css
[name$="-avatar"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

[name$="-avatar"] ~ span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}

[name$="-avatar"]:checked ~ span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px blue;
}
```

```html
PLAYER 1<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="pl-1-avatar" value="a" checked> <span>A</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="pl-1-avatar" value="b"> <span>B</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="pl-1-avatar" value="c"> <span>C</span></label>

<hr>
PLAYER 2<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="pl-2-avatar" value="a" checked> <span>A</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="pl-2-avatar" value="b"> <span>B</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="pl-2-avatar" value="c"> <span>C</span></label>
<hr>

<button id="play">START GAME</button>
```